# How to trace "ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage" warning when it happens for 1 out of 2 environments that share the same pod settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, cocoapods, itms-90809

We solved the "ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage" for the production build of our iOS app by removing "UIWebView" references even from comments and setting minimum AFNetworking version to 2.4. But it still happens for our unpublished beta build. They share the same code base and the lib flags are the same. Our app bundle id is "macro"ed based on environment set on the scheme e.g. 
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "com.arealcompanyname.arealappname${BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX}";
and this works totally fine with making the build with correct icons, services, testflight, etc.

It's hard to trace the problem if the error doesn't point to which library or directory has the problem.
Would it be possible that pods installed binaries come from a different(unupdated) directory during build when on beta? If so how do I trace this problem?

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "AppName BETA" 1.11 (6). Your delivery was successful, but you may
>   wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>   ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more
>   information.

Comment: You might want to check this for more info: https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/527 and https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4428 You can remove the webview files.

Comment: thanks I'll try that out. i saw this from your 2nd link... 
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0', :subspecs => ['Reachability', 'Serialization', 'Security', 'NSURLSession']

the only thing that's odd is why the current state using 2.4 works without warning for submitted production builds but not for submitted beta builds